# Class and Stateless Widget

Tags: flutter, class, difference, statelesswidget

First of all I would like to say that I am new to Flutter.

I don't understand the difference between class and stateless widget. I understand why I'm using stateful , because of setState. but why should I use statless instead of just class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference is actually depends on your application really but using `class` is more preferable in most cases. They are same, for the performance part, if you will not call `setState` in `Widget`. There are other differences like testability and accuracy. I suggest you first watch official flutter tutorial before using which one to use.
[Official tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo)

Comment: You're welcome. To sum it up, use classes but widgets look more pretty :)

Comment: Tamam i understand :D